# How to get an object from PaperTrail version before a given time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

There is an api that returns the widget (not a version) as it looked at the given timestamp.

```
widget.paper_trail.version_at(timestamp)
```

But in my case, I want to get the widget as it looked **before** the given timestamp. So, I would expect there would be a `version_before` api to achieve this scenario. Yet, I haven't found any solutions.

For example, in Dec 2016, there is a man (Mr. A) whose weight is 50kg, and a lady (Ms. B) whose weight is 45kg. A month later, in Jan 2017, the lady's weight is gained to 50kg (consider we update the lady's weight so paper trail records an update event version), while the man's weight remains the same (50kg).

Scenario, I want to see whose weight is 50kg in Jan 2017. I would expect to get the two people as the results.

The following is what I've tried with PaperTrail so far.

```
from_date = '2017-01-01'
to_date   = '2017-01-31'
ids       = []
PaperTrail::Version.where('DATE(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?', from_date, to_date).find_each do |version|
  ids << version.item_id if v.changeset[:weight] && v.changeset[:weight][1] == 50
end
People.where(id: ids) #=> Ms. B
```

Since PaperTrail records only changes/CRUD, I cannot get Mr. A as the result expected.

Has anybody experienced figuring out as my scenario? Any comments or answers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a form generator I am creating as I added `has_paper_trail` after records for my `FormGeneratorForm` model already existed.  There was no versioning available for the existing forms.  My ending solution was to write a short rake task to `touch_with_version` each record in the table updating only the `created_at` timestamp, essentially creating the first version for each form without changing the existing content of the record.

i.e.

```
class VersionExistingForms
  def self.execute
    FormGeneratorForm.find_each(&:touch_with_version)
  end
end
```